# How does Emberjs seemingly extend Javascript's syntax?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, syntax

How does Emberjs accomplish the following syntax in Javascript?

```
var handler = function(){
   console.log('Triggered');
}.on('someEvent');
```

The part of interest is the `.on('whatever')`. I get errors when I try to use this syntax outside of Ember.

Thanks!

Comment: Because JS is a prototype based language everything has a prototype, including functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Comment: `Function.prototype.on = function(...){....}`

Comment: More correctly, they have not extended the syntax. The code in question involves a function literal, and a method call on that function literal. Nothing out of the ordinary there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They did it like this:

````
  /**
    The `on` extension of Javascript's Function prototype is available
    when `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES` or `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES.Function` is
    true, which is the default.

    You can listen for events simply by adding the `on` call to the end of
    your method declarations in classes or mixins that you write. For example:

    ```javascript
    Ember.Mixin.create({
      doSomethingWithElement: function() {
        // Executes whenever the "didInsertElement" event fires
      }.on('didInsertElement')
    });
    ```

    See `Ember.on`.

    @method on
    @for Function
  */
  Function.prototype.on = function() {
    var events = a_slice.call(arguments);
    this.__ember_listens__ = events;
    return this;
  };
}
````

http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js